# Code 608 when using a dapp with a safe infrastructure locally (Fuji Testnet)

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, gnosis-safe

### Context

I have a perfectly working dapp I'm trying to adapt to a Safe App. To test the dapp, I have to use a test network (Avalanche Fuji Testnet here), which is not supported by the current Safe web app. I therefore developed my own local Safe infrastructure for this purpose. I did everything the documentation told me to do. The dapp works well in the Safe iframe, except on the following point:

### Issue

- **Code 608**: The errors below are displayed in a loop as soon as the app is loaded, at intervals of around twenty seconds:

```
- GET http://safe.testnet.MY_DOMAIN/cgw/v1/chains/43113/safes/MY_SAFE_ADDRESS/messages 404 (Not Found)
- Code 608: Error fetching messages (Not Found)
```

### Stack

- React single page app (CRA)
- Soidity Contracts (Avalanche EVM)
- EthersJS to deal with everything web3 (provider, contract calls)
- safe-apps-react-sdk & safe-apps-provider (to be used with Ethers) for the Safe app integration.

Any clues as to where to look for the reason for this issue?

Comment: Do you have the messages endpoint on the transaction service? Can you access it? Have you checked that you're running the latest versions of the services?