# Debugging tools available to better target the errors reported by the safe app and safe provider?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, gnosis-safe

When trying to make my dapp compatible with a safe app, the safe app raised errors when necessary, but for some it's difficult to locate the error in the code (because there's no reference to code logs in the console, as in the case for a code 608 error, [see this topic](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/153415/code-608-when-using-a-dapp-with-a-safe-infrastructure-locally-fuji-testnet)).

Are there any debugging tools available to better target the errors reported by the safe app and safe provider (when not traceable with code logs)?

### Stack

- React single page app (CRA)
- Soidity Contracts (Avalanche EVM)
- EthersJS to deal with everything web3 (provider, contract calls)
- safe-apps-react-sdk & safe-apps-provider (to be used with Ethers) for the Safe app integration